# ILIKE over two columns slow in joined tables

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have two tables:

**products**:

- product_id int
- producer varchar
- status char(1)

**product_names**:

- name_id int
- product_id int fk
- name vharchar
- lang char(2)

products has around 500 000 entries. product_names around 1 000 000

```
        SELECT p.*, n.name, n.lang
        FROM products p
        INNER JOIN product_names n ON 
            n.product_id = e.product_id

        WHERE
                p.status IN ('A', '1', '5', '9')

            AND (
                    n.name ILIKE 'nestle%'
                 OR p.producer ILIKE 'nestle%'
            )
        LIMIT 1
```

If I run ILIKE only on n.name OR only p.product, it takes around 15ms to find results.

If I run ILIKE on both columns in the same time, it takes around 1.2 seconds... 1000x longer!

I tried all possible indexes I know:

products:

```
"p_producer_index20" btree (producer)
"p_producer_index22" btree (producer text_pattern_ops)
"p_producer_index23" gist (producer gist_trgm_ops)
"p_producer_index24" gin (producer gin_trgm_ops)
```

product_names:

```
"p_names_name_index2" btree (name text_pattern_ops)
"p_names_name_trgm_index" gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
```

Am I missing something here or doing something totally wrong?

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for both queries.

Comment: in the meantime, I dropped all indexes, and recreated them ... everything is working perfectly ok now. no idea what caused this.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an index on products.status to get some benefit of an index.
Since because of the OR it probably doesn't make full use of the indexes on those producer and name fields.

And try out:

```
    SELECT p.*, n.name, n.lang
    FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN product_names n 
      ON (p.product_id = n.product_id AND n.name ILIKE 'nestle%')
    WHERE
        p.status IN ('A','1','5','9')
        AND (p.producer ILIKE 'nestle%' OR n.name IS NOT NULL)
    LIMIT 1
```

And you could also [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-analyze.html) the tables to help the query planner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT p.*, n.name, n.lang
        FROM products p
        JOIN product_names n ON n.product_id = e.product_id
        WHERE p.status IN ('A', '1', '5', '9') AND
              n.name ILIKE 'nestle%'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT p.*, n.name, n.lang
        FROM products p
        JOIN product_names n ON n.product_id = e.product_id
        WHERE p.status IN ('A', '1', '5', '9') AND
              p.producer ILIKE 'nestle%') t
LIMIT 1
```